# HTML, Pure Javascript | How to make an element follow the text freshly entered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an effect in which a circle follows the new entered text

Like:
As I type 'H', the circle is behind it, then when I press 'e', the text now visible is 'He' but the circle is behind 'e' now. And this process continues.

The text will be entered in a `<textarea>` and this text coveres half the page.

This is a website and If possible please give the answers with HTML, CSS and Vanilla JS as I haven't learnt JQuery or any other Framwork, Library, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'behind' - is it to the left of the new character (overwriting the previous character) or to the right of the new character but within the textarea?

Comment: Please provide the html you have done till now

Comment: Can you provide an illustration?

Comment: You can do this, e.g. by having a dummy textarea on top of the real one, but could you explain a bit more exactly how this is to function. For example, what is to happen to the circle if the user uses the back arrow to go back to do some editing - is the 'normal' blinking caret still to show while the circle remains at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

In a textarea element I think it is not possible without further ado. But you can use an input element instead. I have built a small prototype that shows you how to do it.

```js
const op = document.querySelector('.output');

function make() {
  const ta = document.querySelector('#textarea input');  
  op.innerHTML = ta.value;
  const nw = ta.value.length < 1 ? 1: ta.value.length;
  
   ta.size= parseInt(nw);
}
```

```css
.w {
  text-align: center;
}

.output {
  background: lightgray;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

#textarea{
  border:1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

#textarea input{  
  border:none;
  background:none;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding:6px;
}

#textarea input:focus{
   outline:none;
}
```

```html
  <div id="textarea" oninput="make()">
    <input size="1" type="text" value=""/>
    <div class="output"></div>  
   </div>
```